# AJAX returning an empty responde

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax is returning an empty array from server

JavaScript

```
function Getmateriasfromserver(callback){
var status_aux;
//Requisição HTTP, por dados provindos do url dado. Caso os dados recebidos sejam os esperados, entra no caso do SUCCESS
return $.ajax({
    url: '../materiasphp/materias.php',
    data: "",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        status_aux = data;
        callback(status_aux);
    }
}
});
```

Php

```
<?php
require('../conexao/conexao.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM materias";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $nome[] = $r['nome'];
    $vagas[] = $r['vagas'];
    $professor[] = $r['professor'];
    $codigo[] = $r['codigo'];
    $dias[] = $r['dias'];
    $local[] = $r['locais'];
    $horario[] = $r['horario'];
}
$json[0] = $nome;
$json[1] = $vagas;
$json[2] = $professor;
$json[3] = $codigo;
$json[4] = $dias;
$json[5] = $local;
$json[6] = $horario;
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I've tried commented the part inside the while statement and create a `$test = "test"` and echo $test and it worked.
And the problem is not the name of the colluns on the table

**EDIT1:** I changed the url path to "../materiasphp/materias.php" and add `dataType: 'json' but now I'm receiving "403 Forbidden" from the server.
If I don't declare the datatype and don't do the json_encode I receive "ArrayArrayArrayArray"

Comment: Why the url has this prefix: `././` It should be absolute.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `././` and not `../../` or `./`? `./` is the root, but `././` would mean `root/root`. `../../` would allow you to go up two directories.

Comment: @webdeb *"It should be absolute"* .... does not have to be, relative will work fine also. Certainly cleaner using absolute but is not a requirement

Comment: @Rodrigo, when you claim ajax is returning empty, how do you know that?

Comment: @webdeb sorry, is ../

Comment: @ObsidianAge hmm thanks man, is ../

Comment: Adding `dataType` does not change the request at all. It only informs jQuery of the expected response type. Nothing in your code should produce a 403 response. Are you absolutely certain that the path `../materiasphp/materias.php` is correct?

Comment: @Phil Yes, because if I send $test = "test" and don't specify the dataType, I receive "test" on data.